# Mover imagem (PictureBox) em formulário

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Como mover uma imagem em um formulário windows form.

Usei o seguinte código:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int tamanhoFundo = picFundo.Width;
    int x = myPic.Location.X;
    int y = myPic.Location.Y;
    while (x < tamanhoFundo)
    {
        int pos = x += 5;
        myPic.Location = new Point(pos, myPic.Location.Y);
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}
```

Até move a imagem, só que fica um rastro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como evitar isto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se a imagem ficar por cima da `picFundo`, antes de chamar o `Thred.Sleep` dê um `Refresh()` no fundo. Olhe o codigo abaixo:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int tamanhoFundo = picFundo.Width;
    int x = myPic.Location.X;
    int y = myPic.Location.Y;
    while (x < tamanhoFundo)
    {
        int pos = x += 5;
        myPic.Location = new Point(pos, myPic.Location.Y);
        picFundo.Refresh();
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}
```

Comment: Era isto mesmo. Valeu, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Isso é ocorrido de uma forma proposital do próprio `System.Windows.Forms`, em causa de aumentar o desempenho da renderização da janela. Mas você pode desativar isso com o método `Refresh()` e `Update()`, os dois são ótimos renderizar sua janela. veja o exemplo baseado no seu código:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  int tamanhoFundo = picFundo.Width;
  int x = myPic.Location.X;
  int y = myPic.Location.Y;
  while (x < tamanhoFundo)
  {
     int pos = x += 5;
     myPic.Location = new Point(pos, myPic.Location.Y);
     myPic.Refresh(); myPic.Update();
     Thread.Sleep(250); // Também é bom reduzir o tempo de Sleep, pois os métodos Refresh() e Update() consomem um pouco de memória para re-criar o componente, então, de 500 vamos colocar 250.
  }
}
```